# jquery toggle on dt element working in Firefox but not other browsers

Tags: jquery, list, toggle, definition

The following works in Firefox but in no other browser. Is the parent child relationship of `<dl>`s different in the different browsers?

```
$('dd').parent().find('h3').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).next('dd').slideDown(500);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).next('dd').slideUp(500);
    }
);
```

HTML looks like:

```
<dt><h3>stuff to be clicked</h3></dt>
<dd><p>stuff in dd might look like this with internal elements</p>
    <ul>
        <li>stuff1</li>
        <li>stuff2 </li>
        <li>stuff3 </li>
   </ul>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function logic is wrong, but it's working in firefox since it deals with your HTML different than other browsers.

The `next()` function looks at the immediate sibling of the element in question. You are doing this on the `h3` element:

```
<dt><h3>stuff to be clicked</h3></dt>
```

As you can see, there are no immediate siblings to the `h3` tag. It has no siblings (and thus no `next()`).

So why does firefox work? Because your HTML is also invalid. According to the [specifications of the `DT` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-DT) the `dt` tag takes only `inline` elements and the `h3` tag is not an inline tag. Why does this matter? Because different browsers deal differently with invalid documents. Firefox, in this case, kicks out the `h3` tag or the `dt` tag, leaving your document structure like this:

```
<dt></dt>
<h3>stuff to be clicked</h3>
<dd><p>stuff in dd might look like this with internal elements</p>
    <ul>
        <li>stuff1</li>
        <li>stuff2 </li>
        <li>stuff3 </li>
   </ul>
</dd>
```

So in Firefox' case, the `h3` element actually becomes siblings with the `dd` tag, and your code works. However, in other browsers (such as Chrome, which is tested on), the `h3` tag remains inside the `dt` tag and your code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks very much! This helps (though I'm feeling extremely foolish too!) Learning more every day!